# How to redirect Vue/Nuxt SPA Page automatically

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

#### Summery

I'm creating Vue/Nuxt application by SPA mode.
To generate `/.dist` file, I execute `nuxt generate`

```
pages
  ├ index.vue
  └ test.vue
```

I want to know how to redirect `/` to `/test` path by Nuxt.

##### What I tried

I tried middleware and module, but they do not work.

https://github.com/nuxt-community/redirect-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple workaround is to use fetch hook in the index page to change rout to /test; Here is the code:

```js
// index.vue
fetch() {
  this.$router.push('./test');
}
```